# DNN 2sxc Image Manager fails - activate old Telerik components

Tags: 2sxc

I'm using DNN 8.0.4 and the 2sxc v. 8.7.0 application.

I'm unable to use the DNN Image Manager within any of the sub-applications to link to an existing image.  When I try to use it, I get a popup error message that says:

"can't connect to the dialog - you are probably running a new DNN (v.8+) and didn't activate the old Telerik components.  Please install these in the host > extensions to get this to work."

I know how to install DNN extensions, but exactly what do I install and where do I find it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In our 08.00.04 installation the Telerik components seem to be already installed but 2SXC is still asking to install the components for using the image manager. Using the latest 2SXC 8.8.1.

[image]

Comment: In our installation the Telerik components are installed under Libraries and the DLLs are also in the Bin folder. Still it does work and 2SXC does give me the error message that the components are not available. Just like "david wendelen" mentions below. This seems to be the case in any of the latest 2SXC versions. Any ideas how to get this to work @iJungleBoy ?

Answer (score 0):

DNN removed all telerik controls in V8 but wasn't able to provide a replacement for things like like the file-picker yet.

See http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/dnn-8-breaking-changes and http://www.dnnsoftware.com/community-blog/cid/155269/a-break-with-the-past

The solution is to install the telerik components which are included. They are located in

- Host > Extensions
- Then you are in a tab showing *installed extensions* and you want to go to the tab showing *available extensions*

Scroll down, you will find some collapsed "accordeon" style elements showing various parts like "Authentication Components", "Libraries", etc.

In the **Libraries** section you will find the Telerik components, ready to install. Install them, and you're good to go.

Comment: Do you mean:
DotNetNuke Telerik Web Components  
Provides Telerik Components for DotNetNuke. 
v8.0.1 

Because if you do, that's been marked as installed all along.

Comment: That is the item. Note that it's not installed unless you actively did that. So if it thinks it's installed, you should verify if it is or not. AFAIK if it is installed, you should find telerik-DLLs in the /bin folder. they are 20MB each, so hard to miss :)

Comment: I am experiencing this again with a site DNN 08.00.04 and 2sxc 8.9.0. I have Telerik Components already installed and updated but getting 404 when trying to open Image Manager? For DNN site using third party module 'will be required to update their references to the new library and compile against Platform 8' but on other sites the above was fine?

Comment: I had a broken resource path (url to actual file), solution was to remove image (i.e. 'File:234') and then re click Image Manager icon to reset file picker again. Note: clicking on file picker with old image url (image moved to a different folder) in input threw 404 error

Comment: Note: the move-problem only occurs, when you manually move the file using windows-explorer. If you move it in the DNN admin, the references are automatically updated by DNN